# Apple Mail: Automatically pre-fill BCC field with address

Tags: email, apple-mail, bcc

Our company uses a CRM which features an e-mail integration functionality - CCing or BCCing a specific address will cause that e-mail to be captured into the system.

We have set up our mail server to forward all *incoming* mail automatically to our CRM.

However, for outgoing mail, we currently have to manually add this address into the BCC field within Apple Mail.

I've seen methods like [this one](http://email.about.com/od/macosxmailtips/qt/et_auto_bcc.htm) that automatically replace the BCC field of all outgoing mail, however I can't find any documented way (on Stack Overflow or otherwise) to automatically populate the 'BCC' field when composing a new message. I believe Postbox and Thunderbird offer this feature, but is there a way to do this in Apple Mail?

To be clear, I'm imagining a plugin which would automatically populate the 'BCC' field of a new message *or* a reply/reply-all/forward with a predetermined address. This way it can be deleted manually if necessary. The problem with the automatic BCCing is that it can't be turned off manually.

Answer (score 1):

I've been searching for this as well and this is the only response I've seen that works involves always adding a `Bcc` header, which however also overrides any Bcc-recipients you might set manually:

```
defaults write com.apple.mail UserHeaders '{"Bcc" = "bcc@address"; }'
```

Also ensure no custom headers have been set yet; for full instructions see http://email.about.com/od/macosxmailtips/qt/et_auto_bcc.htm

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! The article you have found is helpful, but it's important to include the key points in the answer, in case the link you have provided stops working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It has worked for me for over a year.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
  Dim R As Outlook.Recipient
  Dim Address$

  Address = "abc@domain.com"

  Set R = Item.Recipients.Add(Address)
  R.Type = olBCC
  R.Resolve
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you add a short description on how to employ this?